# I am unable to find the reason for this merge sort algorithm to not work

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, nodes, mergesort

I had to create a circular linked List class for an assignment with a bunch of methods (only relevant ones are being shown here) and I am unable to complete the last task which is adding a sorting algorithm to it. I can only ever get the output to "1, 19", if I try to change things around all that happened was that I got stuck in an endless loop. I know I made some super stupid simple and obvious error somewhere but I cannot seem to find it by myself, would really appreciate the help, thank you.

```
public class List {
    private class Node {
        private int value;
        private Node next;

        private Node(int element, Node next) {
            this.value = element;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    private Node head;

    public List(int[] values) {
        this.addAll(values);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = { 1, 9, 42, 3, 7 };
        List l = new List(input)
        l.sort();
        l.add(19);
        System.out.println(l.toString());
    }

    public int length() {
        if (this.head == null)
            return 0;
        Node current = this.head.next;
        int count = 1;
        while (current != this.head) {
            current = current.next;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void add(int value) {
        if (this.length() == 0) {
            this.head = new Node(value, null);
            this.head.next = this.head;
            return;
        }
        Node current = this.head.next;
        while (current.next != this.head)
            current = current.next;
        current.next = new Node(value, this.head);
    }

    public void addAll(int[] values) {
        for (int value : values)
            this.add(value);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        if (this.length() == 0)
            return s;
        s = this.head.value + "";
        if (this.length() == 1)
            return s;
        Node current = this.head.next;
        for (int i = 1; i < this.length(); i++) {
            s += ", " + current.value;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return s;
    }


    private static Node mergeSort(Node pHead) {
        if (pHead.next == pHead)
            return pHead;
        Node slow = pHead, fast = pHead.next;
        while (fast != pHead) {
            fast = fast.next;
            if (fast == pHead)
                break;
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next;
        }
        Node left = pHead, right = slow.next, temp = new List().new Node(-1, null), tempHead = temp;
        slow.next = pHead;
        left = mergeSort(left);
        right = mergeSort(right);
        while (!(left == pHead || right == pHead)) {
            if (left.value < right.value) {
                temp.next = left;
                left = left.next;
            } else {
                temp.next = right;
                right = right.next;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        while (left != pHead || right != pHead) {
            if (left != pHead) {
                temp.next = left;
                left = left.next;
            } else {
                temp.next = right;
                right = right.next;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return tempHead;
    }
```

I tried narrowing it down, but I do not really trust that and I failed to pinpoint the issue anyways sadly. Every other method here works perfectly fine and has been tested, it is just the sorting algorithm that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The initial problem occurs with `right = mergeSort(right);`, because the (last node of right).next = `pHead` instead of `right` .

In order for this approach to work, a single circular list is split into two circular lists, the two circular lists are sorted, then the two sorted circular lists are merged into a single circular list:

```
    private static Node mergeSort(Node head) {
        if (head.next == head)
            return head;
        Node slow = head;                   // split into two circular lists
        Node fast = head;
        while (fast.next != head) {
            fast = fast.next;
            if (fast.next == head)
                break;
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next;
        }
        Node left = head;
        Node right = slow.next;
        slow.next = left;                   //  end of  left = left
        fast.next = right;                  //  end of right = right
        left = mergeSort(left);             // sort left  circular list
        right = mergeSort(right);           // sort right circular list
        Node lhead = left;                  // merge two  circular lists
        Node rhead = right;
        Node temp = new List().new Node(-1, null);
        Node thead = temp;
        while(true){
            if (left.value < right.value) {
                temp.next = left;
                temp = left;
                left = left.next;
                if (left != lhead)          // if not end of left list
                    continue;               //  continue
                temp.next = right;          // else append right list
                while (right.next != rhead)
                    right = right.next;
                right.next = thead.next;    //  set end to new head
                break;
            } else {
                temp.next = right;
                temp = right;
                right = right.next;
                if (right != rhead)         // if not end of right list
                    continue;               //  continue
                temp.next = left;           // else append left list
                while (left.next != lhead)
                    left = left.next;
                left.next = thead.next;     //  set end to new head
                break;
            }
        }
        return thead.next;
    }
```

Note - no actual merging occurs until the first instance of a split that results in two circular lists with one node each. Then the merging will follow the call chain up (larger lists) and down (smaller lists) until a single sorted circular list is produced.

---

Alternative and more efficient bottom up merge sort for linked list. Uses an array of head nodes `an` to lists terminated by null, where `an[i]` is null or a reference to the head node of a list with 2^i nodes. Nodes are merged into the array, then the array is merged to create a single list, then the list is traversed to set the last_node.next = this.head to make it circular again.

```
    // assumes list has less than 2^sz nodes (sz = 32)
    public void sort() {
        // if < 2 nodes, return
        if (this.head == null || this.head.next == this.head)
            return;
        final int sz = 32;                  // array size
        Node[] an = new Node[sz];           // array of head nodes to lists
        Node node;
        Node next;
        int i;
        node = this.head;
        // merge nodes into array
        do{
            next = node.next;
            node.next = null;
            for(i = 0; i < sz && an[i] != null; i++){
                node = merge(an[i], node);
                an[i] = null;
            }
            an[i] = node;
            node = next;
        }while(node != this.head);
        // merge array into single list
        for(i = 0; i < sz && an[i] == null; i++);
        node = an[i++];
        while(true){
            for( ; i < sz && an[i] == null; i++);
            if (i == sz)
                break;
            node = merge(an[i++], node);
        }
        this.head = node;
        while(node.next != null)            // make list circular
            node = node.next;
        node.next = this.head;
    }

    // merge two already sorted lists
    static Node merge(Node lft, Node rgt) {
        Node temp = new List().new Node(-1, null);
        Node dest = temp;
        while(true){
            if(lft.value <= rgt.value){
                dest.next = lft;
                dest = lft;
                lft = lft.next;
                if(lft == null){
                    dest.next = rgt;
                    return temp.next;
                }
            } else {
                dest.next = rgt;
                dest = rgt;
                rgt = rgt.next;
                if(rgt == null){
                    dest.next = lft;
                    return temp.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```